# Passing entire structure to a function and display the contents C

Tags: c, structure

I have been stuck on this for a while now.The program reads lines from a text file into array of structures. Here is a few lines so you get an idea of what is being stored into array of structures.

```
A|Baltimore Orioles|Oriole Park|333 West Camden Street|Baltimore|MD|21201|(410) 685-9800|orioles.com
N|Washington Nationals|Nationals Park|1500 South Capitol Street, SE|Washington|DC|20003-1507|(202) 675-6287|nationals.com
```

There is no problem when it comes to loading the arrays with correct data. I tested the contents using this piece of code and it displays correct data.

```
        scanf("%i",&userChoice);

        if(userChoice == 1){
        for(index=0; index<count; index++)
        {
            if(strcmp("A", teams[index].leagueName)== 0)
                {

                    americanLeague(&teams[index]);


                }
        }
        }
```

The program has a main menu and option 1 is to display all teams from American League or "A" from text file. Now I don't want the for loop/if statement to run in main function.I want it just to run the if statement for userchoice and call the americanLeague function. Here is my attempt

```
scanf("%i",&userChoice);

if(userChoice == 1){

                    americanLeague(&teams[0]);


        }
```

This just calls americanLeague function

```
void americanLeague(team_t *aTeamPtr)
{
        int index;

        for(index=0; index<=MAX_TEAMS; index++){
        if(strcmp("A", aTeamPtr[index].leagueName)== 0)
            {

                printf("LEAGUE:%s TEAM:%s PARKNAME:%s ADDRESS:%s CITY:%s STATE:%s ZIPCODE:%s PHONE#:%s WEBADDRESS:%s\n\n",
                                                 aTeamPtr[index].leagueName, aTeamPtr[index].teamName,
                                                 aTeamPtr[index].parkName, aTeamPtr[index].teamAddress,
                                                 aTeamPtr[index].teamCity, aTeamPtr[index].teamState,
                                                 aTeamPtr[index].zipCode, aTeamPtr[index].phoneNumber,
                                                 aTeamPtr[index].webAddress);


            }
        }
}
```

Here is my attempt to try and display teams info passing array of structures into another function.The code doesn't work, but it doesn't give me any errors it just outputs blank spaces.I will also add structure and how I read file just in case.

```
typedef struct
{
    char leagueName[LEAGUE_NAME + 1];
    char teamName[LEN_NAME + 1];
    char parkName[PARK_NAME + 1];
    char teamAddress[TEAM_ADDRESS + 1];
    char teamCity[TEAM_CITY + 1];
    char teamState[TEAM_STATE + 1];
    char zipCode[ZIP_CODE + 1];
    char phoneNumber[PHONE_NUMBER + 1];
    char webAddress[WEB_ADDRESS + 1];


} team_t;

int main(void)
{
    FILE * filePtr;
    int index, count;
    char line[LEN_LINE + 1];
    char repeat;
    team_t teams[MAX_LINES];
    filePtr = fopen("MLBteams.txt", "r");
    if(filePtr == NULL)
    {
        printf("Unable to open file.\n");
    }
    else
    {
        index = 0;
        while(index<MAX_LINES && fgets(line, LEN_LINE, filePtr))
        {
            if(9 == sscanf(line,"%5[^|]| %40[^|]| %35[^|]| %40[^|]| %30[^|]| %5[^|]| %10[^|]| %30[^|]| %25[^\n]", teams[index].leagueName, teams[index].teamName,
                                                                                                                   teams[index].parkName, teams[index].teamAddress,
                                                                                                                   teams[index].teamCity, teams[index].teamState,
                                                                                                                   teams[index].zipCode, teams[index].phoneNumber,
                                                                                                                   teams[index].webAddress)

               )
            {
                index++;
            }
        }
        fclose(filePtr);
        count = index;
```

There is no problem when reading correct data into array of structures.I already tested the output several times within main function.Anyways any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Would it be possible to reduce this down to only what's wrong and the code that is associated with your problem?

Comment: Sorry, being a beginner I am struggling to explain myself clearly and posted too much it seems.The program up above reads the text file and stores data into the different members of the structure which is working correctly. The file has options as 1)display all american league teams 2)search by name etc. I have working pieces of code that do that for me correctly, but in the main function. I want to have different functions that do those separate options so my attempt to do that is up above the second to last piece of code.

Answer (score 0):

You're apparently passing an array (or pointer) to a function that also treats it as a pointer to a single instance. You can see the difference in your code where you do `aTeamPtr[index].leagueName` but also `aTeamPtr->leagueName`.

Which one do you want?

Consider this code and its output:

```
int size = 10;

struct iint {
    int i;
};

void foo(struct iint* i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < size; ++j) {
        printf("%d", i[j].i);
    }
    printf("\n%d\n", i->i);
}

int main() {
    struct iint i[size];
    for (int j = 0; j < size; ++j) {
        i[j].i = j;
    }
    foo(i);
    return 0;
}

// Output:
// 0123456789
// 0
```

That's because a pointer to an array points at the first element. C doesn't care if you choose to use them interchangeably.

Comment: Don't I have to use aTeamPtr->leagueName since I passed it as pointer? I tried so many different ways at this point I just want it to work. As I showed up above I just want to be able to pass array of structures to another function and use the for loop/if statement to display the data.

Comment: I think  you actually want `aTeamPtr[index].leagueName` (and so on) everywhere you you used `->`. @AdrianAlba

Comment: I don't fully understand the code. It seems like you are using some sort of counter when calling function. In my function void americanLeague(team_t *aTeamPtr) instead of using the pointer I use a counter? like void americanLeague(team_t* i). Then I will be able to use aTeamPtr[index].leagueName?

Comment: No, I'm not using any additional counters than you. When you do your check, that's inside a loop. You do your work `if(strcmp("A", aTeamPtr[index].leagueName)== 0)` so the right element to print is the one at `index`. @AdrianAlba

Comment: All I'm doing in `foo` is showing you I can treat a pointer (that points to an array) as an array or the first element in the array. @AdrianAlba

Comment: Sorry I just started using array of structures and what I have been using is limited to typedef structures.Not sure if I understood completely is when printing I switch the aTeamPtr->leaguename when displaying to aTeamPtr[index].leagueName? Also thanks a lot for tanking the time to help

Comment: That's right. @AdrianAlba Once you know which one it is (could be *any* in the array at that exact moment) use that index to work with that specific team. Glad to help!

Comment: I had this piece of code if(strcmp("A", aTeamPtr[index].leagueName)== 0) in my original attempt. Now I tried change the address from the print statement to aTeamPtr[index].leagueName, aTeamPtr[index].teamName,etc. It still provides no errors and just outputs lines. Thinking it has to do with parameters when calling function which the code is nationalLeague(&teams[index]); and also here is code of the function header with parameters void americanLeague(team_t *aTeamPtr).

Comment: You're losing me now. I'm not sure what to make of your last comment but it seems to be veering away from what you originally posted. Please answer the following question: *When you call `americanLeague` (for example) do you pass it an array of teams or a single team?* In your example here, you use it as an array (you iterate over it!) as well as a pointer to single team (you do `->` on the same pointer you *treat as an array*!).

Comment: The program is reading 30 teams from a file into array of structures.When user selects option 1(which shows all american league teams) the americanLeague function is called. I want to show all the american league teams with all their respective information(name,address,etc). I have the piece of code that allowed me to do this successfully within the main function though.

Comment: when trying to replicate in another function

Comment: Ok, so it's an array. There's no difference in the code that you use in main or the other function. The only difference is you tried to complicate your life by passing a pointer to a function that *really* wants an array. While that has no meaningful difference to the language, you'd be better off doing things explicitly to help you (and others) reason your code. Anywho, do as I said long ago. If you have any updates for your code, ask another question or update the code in this one as you go along and have yet to receive an answer.

Comment: I updated the second to last piece of code to what you said and it still only outputs blank lines. Also MAX_TEAMS IS #define MAX_TEAMS 30

Comment: Sorry to say but that doesn't seem possible with the code you have here and I can't spend anymore time on this. Your updated code will ***at the very least*** print the league name of every american league team. That is self evident by the fact you can't print unless the condition is true after resolving the same league name against what you believe to be the correct league name. Good luck; will delete this in due time @AdrianAlba.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help.Anyways for what is worth in the call I replaced index for 0 americanLeague(&teams[0]);.Then I switched back to -> in print statement for americanLeague function.Result is now it prints out the first teams information all of it 15 times(which is the amount of American league teams in file).

Comment: I think you should take the time to understand what you're doing rather than finding a solution to your attempts at doing something you don't understand.  It sounds like you're headed towards that understanding but you're still referencing a call I've yet to see in your question. As such, I bid you good luck again. This will be my last com absent a significant edit, clarification, or refutation of my answer.

Comment: Good news is that I figured it out and now the code is working well.You were telling me all this time.I was just tired and wasn't using my head. Apologize must've been annoying trying to explain.Anyways updated the code and again thanks for the help.

Comment: No problem, glad to help. If my answer helped solve it, consider upvoting it and/or accepting it as the solution. @Adrian